# Is there a name for syllables connected with hyphens which might be read as multiple words?

Tags: grammar, hyphenation, syllables

Is there a name for syllables connected with hyphens which can be read as multiple words?

For example in one of my songs I have the lines:

When you escape from, re-hab-its
… more than your soul, cares to recall.

In the song you hear "rehab it's" but in the printed lyrics it's overlaying rehab and habits.

Another example is the line "I see where our time can bend ... new talk or just a-mend."

In other words I not only want to indicate to the reader that this is wordplay but have a name for it.

Thanks.

Comment: It's a visual pun. There is no specific word, because there are many different ways of expressing such things with font face, text style, and so on.

Comment: @JasonBassford  Visual pun is perfectly good. Thank you.